# Validation failed for one or more entities while trying to add a new product

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I try to add a new product and therefore add new images to product's folder, this error shows up:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. Exception Details:
>   System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation
>   failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property
>   for more details.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddProduct()
{
    if (Session["User"] == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Register");

    string username = Session["User"].ToString();
    string rolename = Session["Role"].ToString();
    if (rolename == "Seller" || rolename == "Admin")
    {
        var quser = db.Tbl_User.Where(a => a.User_Username == username && a.Tbl_Role.Role_Name == rolename).SingleOrDefault();
        if (quser != null)
        {
            var quser1 = db.Tbl_Identity.Where(a => a.Identity_Userid == quser.User_ID && a.Identity_Confirm == true).SingleOrDefault();
            if (quser1 != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["State"] = "Error";
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["State"] = "Error";
            return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["State"] = "Error";
        return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile");
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(Tbl_Product p, HttpPostedFileBase imageindex, HttpPostedFileBase[] picgallery, string TagProduct, string cat1_id)
{
    if (Session["User"] == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Register");

    string username = Session["User"].ToString();
    string rolename = Session["Role"].ToString();

    if (rolename == "Seller" || rolename == "Admin")
    {
        var quser = db.Tbl_User.Where(a => a.User_Username == username && a.Tbl_Role.Role_Name == rolename).SingleOrDefault();
        if (quser != null)
        {
            var quser1 = db.Tbl_Identity.Where(a => a.Identity_Userid == quser.User_ID && a.Identity_Confirm == true).SingleOrDefault();
            if (quser1 != null)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();

                if (imageindex == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "chose image";
                    return View();
                }

                //-------------------------------------------
                //  Check the image mime types
                //-------------------------------------------
                if (imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpg"
                    && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpeg"
                    && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/pjpeg"
                    && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/gif"
                    && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/x-png"
                    && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/png")
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = " bad format ";
                    return View();
                }

                //-------------------------------------------
                //  Check the image extension
                //-------------------------------------------
                if (Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpg"
                    && Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".png"
                    && Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".gif"
                    && Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpeg")
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "  bad file ";
                    return View();
                }

                if (imageindex.ContentLength >= 512000)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = " size error";
                    return View();
                }

                string rndname = rnd.Next(1, 999).ToString() + "-" + imageindex.FileName;
                imageindex.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Content/_images/product/" + rndname));
                Tbl_Product t = new Tbl_Product();
                t.Product_PicIndex = rndname;
                t.Product_AllOff = p.Product_AllOff;
                t.Product_Date = DateTime.Now;
                t.Product_ExitCount = p.Product_ExitCount;
                t.Product_Groupid = Convert.ToInt32(cat1_id);
                t.Product_IsDownload = p.Product_IsDownload;
                t.Product_Name = p.Product_Name;
                t.Product_Off = p.Product_Off;
                t.Product_Price = p.Product_Price;
                t.Product_Text = p.Product_Text;
                t.Product_Userid = quser.User_ID;
                t.Product_Visit = 0;
                t.Product_Weight = p.Product_Weight;
                t.Product_Active = false;

                db.Tbl_Product.Add(t);

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges() > 0))
                {
                    var tagname = TagProduct.Trim().Split('-');

                    foreach (var item1 in tagname)
                    {
                        Tbl_Tags tg = new Tbl_Tags()
                        {
                            Tag_Proid = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault().Product_ID,
                            Tag_Name = item1.Trim()
                        };

                        db.Tbl_Tags.Add(tg);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    if (picgallery != null)
                    {
                        List<Tbl_Pic> lstpic = new List<Tbl_Pic>();
                        foreach (var item in picgallery)
                        {
                            string namepic = rnd.Next().ToString() + "-" + item.FileName;

                            if (item == null)
                            {
                                var qproid = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                var qtagid = db.Tbl_Tags.Where(a => a.Tag_Proid == qproid.Product_ID).ToList();

                                db.Tbl_Tags.RemoveRange(qtagid);
                                db.Tbl_Product.Remove(qproid);
                                db.SaveChanges();

                                ViewBag.Error = "chose an image";
                                return View();
                            }

                            //-------------------------------------------
                            //  Check the image mime types
                            //-------------------------------------------
                            if (imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpg"
                                && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpeg"
                                && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/pjpeg"
                                && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/gif"
                                && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/x-png"
                                && imageindex.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/png")
                            {
                                var qproid = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                var qtagid = db.Tbl_Tags.Where(a => a.Tag_Proid == qproid.Product_ID).ToList();

                                db.Tbl_Tags.RemoveRange(qtagid);
                                db.Tbl_Product.Remove(qproid);
                                db.SaveChanges();

                                ViewBag.Error = " wrong format ";
                                return View();
                            }

                            //-------------------------------------------
                            //  Check the image extension
                            //-------------------------------------------
                            if (Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpg"
                                && Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".png"
                                && Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".gif"
                                && Path.GetExtension(imageindex.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpeg")
                            {
                                var qproid = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                var qtagid = db.Tbl_Tags.Where(a => a.Tag_Proid == qproid.Product_ID).ToList();

                                db.Tbl_Tags.RemoveRange(qtagid);
                                db.Tbl_Product.Remove(qproid);
                                db.SaveChanges();

                                ViewBag.Error = " wrong format ";
                                return View();
                            }


                            if (item.ContentLength <= 512000)
                            {
                                Tbl_Pic pic = new Tbl_Pic();
                                pic.Pic_Proid = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault().Product_ID;
                                item.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Content/_images/product/Gallery/" + namepic));
                                var x = db.Tbl_Pic.OrderByDescending(a => a.Pic_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (x == null)
                                {
                                    pic.Pic_ID = 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    pic.Pic_ID = x.Pic_ID + 1;
                                }

                                pic.Pic_Name = namepic;
                                lstpic.Add(pic);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var qproid = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                var qtagid = db.Tbl_Tags.Where(a => a.Tag_Proid == qproid.Product_ID).ToList();

                                db.Tbl_Tags.RemoveRange(qtagid);
                                db.Tbl_Product.Remove(qproid);
                                db.SaveChanges();

                                ViewBag.Error = "wrong size";
                                return View();
                            }
                        }

                        db.Tbl_Pic.AddRange(lstpic);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var qproid = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                        var qtagid = db.Tbl_Tags.Where(a => a.Tag_Proid == qproid.Product_ID).ToList();

                        db.Tbl_Tags.RemoveRange(qtagid);
                        db.Tbl_Product.Remove(qproid);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        ViewBag.Error = "chose an image";
                        return View();
                    }

                    var qprorat = db.Tbl_Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault();

                    var iduser = db.Tbl_User.Where(a => a.User_ID == qprorat.Product_Userid).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (iduser != null)
                    {
                        iduser.User_Rating = iduser.User_Rating + 10;

                        db.Tbl_User.Attach(iduser);
                        db.Entry(iduser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    var qsmtp = db.Tbl_Setting.FirstOrDefault().Smtp;
                    var qemail = db.Tbl_Setting.FirstOrDefault().Email;
                    var qpassword = db.Tbl_Setting.FirstOrDefault().Password;
                    // TempData["OK"] ="added successfully";
                    TempData["Result"] = "OK";

                    Email email = new Email();
                    email.SendEmail(qsmtp, qemail, qpassword, quser.User_Email, "");
                    Tbl_Message m = new Tbl_Message();
                    m.Message_Body = "";
                    m.Message_Date = DateTime.Now;
                    m.Message_Read = false;
                    m.Message_Title = "new product added";
                    m.Message_UserGet = quser.User_ID;
                    db.Tbl_Message.Add(m);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("ListProduct");
                }//end savchange
                else
                {
                    TempData["Result"] = "Error";
                    return RedirectToAction("ListProduct");
                }
            }//end quser1
            else
            {
                TempData["Result"] = "Error";
                return RedirectToAction("ListProduct");
            }
        }//end quser
        else
        {
            TempData["State"] = "Error";
            return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile");
        }
    }//end role admin or seller
    else
    {
        TempData["State"] = "Error";
        return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile");
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be able to `See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.` by exploring the exception object.  It should be accessible in the locals window of the debugger.

Comment: yes I see that but can't figure out how to fix.

Comment: So...  What kinds of errors does the EntityValidationErrors property say you have?

Comment: [DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +169
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +27
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20

Comment: fardashahr3.Controllers.ProfileController.AddProduct(Tbl_Product p, HttpPostedFileBase imageindex, HttpPostedFileBase[] picgallery, String TagProduct, String cat1_id) in C:\Users\arya\OneDrive\Programming\ASP\fardashahr\fardashahr3\fardashahr3\Controllers\ProfileController.cs:240
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +280
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22